# Does exists one algorithmic to convert a Linear Grammar Right to a Linear Grammar Left?

Tags: grammar

Does exists one algorithmic to convert a Linear Grammar Right to the equal Linear Grammar Left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every right-linear grammar, there exists an equivalent left-linear grammar that generates the same language, and vice-versa.

- Use the grammar to build the FSA that recognizes the language generated by the original grammar.
- Swap initial states with final states.
- Invert arrows orientation.
- If multiple initial states are present, set them as not initial, create a dummy initial state and link it with them using spontaneous moves.
- From the modified FSA, obtain another right-linear grammar, using the "standard" approach.
- Reverse the right side of every production of the grammar.

You should get an equivalent left-linear grammar.

Comment: do you have any sources for this?